# ajax success response load to divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three forms and using this jquery function

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
            $('#setInfo').fadeOut('500').empty().fadeIn('500').append(response);
        }
    });
        return false;
    });
```

to submit the form datas, but with this function i am stuck at loading the response at one particular div.

The data i send always have **action=email**, **action=settings**, etc depending on the form.

So how i can use it to load the response of settings in another div and email in another div and all other default in current div.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a javascript variable to capture the intended target before submitting the request via AJAX then use the contents of that variable to determine the DIV to populate when the request returns.

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var target = $('#action').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
            var div = $('#setInfo');
            if (target == 'settings') {
               div = $('#settings');
            }
            else if (target == 'email') {
               div = $('#email');
            }
            div.fadeOut('500').html(response).fadeIn('500');
        }
    });
        return false;
});
```

Note I also changed it to set the HTML with the response before fading it in to avoid the possibility of it "blinking."

Comment: you got it wrong. by data i mean data: action=email&user=name...and so on

Comment: Given that you are serializing the form, there would need to be an input named "action" whose value is used to determine which DIV to load.  I'm not sure how else you would be populating this form parameter given your code.

Answer (score 0):

added a id of target to  then

```
var target = $(this).find('#target').val();
```

later used tvanfossons code for loading